# How to hide a user's name and phone number in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, omniauth

Via my Rails App, user "A" can post something (doesn't matter what it is) in a listings type of app and then other users can search for these posts. Simple stuff.

Now if another user let say user "B" searches for a post, finds it and wants to contact the user who posted it, I'm not sure what the best way would be. I don't want the phone number and email of the user "A" who posts to be visible, but user "B" must still be able to find it.

I'm using Omniauth_Facebook for authentication.

Not sure if I should post any code?

Here is an example from the Gumtree website below (See circles marked in red):

[image]

Comment: If you won't supply a phone number or email, in what manner would you like user "B" to contact user "A"?  Or is that your question?

Comment: what about a personal message system there "B" can post something only visible to "A" and can decide to respond on this in either a personal message again or in case "B" provided other contact information over these channels. 

In case "A" knows "B" he can give privileges to him for seeing his contact information, so it would only be hidden for those laking the privileges.

Comment: I added a image. My problem is creating a model for all of this to take place.